# Keep NaN values using apply and lambda in python

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, apply

I am working with python and I have a list of value in column A including some NaN values.
I need to code them as 1 and 0 depending if they are above or below the median (0.4). I've tried the code below which is working fairly well

```
df["A_median"] = (df["A"].apply(lambda count: 0 if count<median_a else 1))
```

But it is giving me the NaN values as 1 instead of keeping them.

```
  A   A_median
36.6  1
NaN   1
NaN   1
0.1   0
```

The final table instead should be as follow

```
  A   A_median
36.6  1
NaN   NaN
NaN   NaN
7     0
```

Any idea on how I can fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it:

```
median_a = 0.4
df['A_median'] = (df['A'] > median_a).where(df.A.notna())
```

Output:

```
      A  A_median
0  36.6       1.0
1   NaN       NaN
2   NaN       NaN
3   0.1       0.0
```